# Packages needed in Custom Image of Ubuntu to work with Juju

Tags: juju, openstack

Hi am trying to run Juju in my existing Openstack Infrastructure.
Since we don`t have direct access to internet, i need to change/modify my image and information of proxy.

So far what i have understood is we need:-

1. cloud-init
2. A user with name "Ubuntu"

It will be good if we can add more in the thread so it becomes easy to use Juju with custom Ubuntu Images as for internal Infra and conditions Cloud Image might not be the only option.

Although i am also looking at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images#Ubuntu_Cloud_Guest_images_on_Local_Hypervisor_Natty_onward  a smoser suggested and see if i rework and modify the image as per need.

I will populate the list with info. :)

Answer (score 5):

That should be all thats needed. Juju will self-bootstrap any additional packages needed via cloud-init.

Comment: I would also like to see package zookeeper added, i would love to zookeeper in cloud image but as Smoser said the size of including dep will be go like another 120 MB or more.